Help identifying police procedural drama tv show from early to mid 2000s
The lead actress was blonde.  They were all cops, or FBI, or some sort of law enforcement division.  I think another guy on the team played a minor role in one of the Matrix movies.  I think it aired on Fox, but it may have been on a different network or cable show.  It would have ran sometime between maybe 2003 to 2006-ish, but only aired for one season.  The blonde actress seemed very young. The team often used her as bait to catch criminals. I think the title scene might have used a lot of green. Seriously, figuring out the name of this TV show is really bugging me.  It's a cop show, and it feels like something Fox would put out.

Was it The Inside? It was a Fox show from 2005, starring Rachel Nichols as Rebecca Locke, a rookie FBI agent assigned to a violent crimes task force because her past as a child abduction victim gives her special insight.  The showrunners were Howard Gordon and Tim Minear, and the cast included Adam Baldwin, Katie Finneran, and Peter Coyote.  
In the pilot episode, iirc, Rebecca fit the victim profile type and was used to lure the criminal.

Yeah. Dude, I totally think it was The Inside. I seriously googled for hours. I must have mistaken Adam Baldwin (who has been in a bunch of sci-fi stuff) for an agent in the matrix. I seriously searched the internet for hours trying to figure out the name of this show. Thank you much!

@MAC You're welcome! Consider accepting this as the answer--it'll also help get your rep up to where you can leave comments :).

An incredibly not-related sidenote: I remember when watching the pilot, that after Coyote's character told Rebecca she could pack her bags and take the metro directly to the airport, yelling at the TV: "There's no metro station at LAX!" (you have to take a shuttle bus). And then being utterly delighted that that was actually a plot point.
